# How put select label on the left in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this problem:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Select list:</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" style="display: inline-block;">Select list:</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Select list:</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Select list:</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default">Filtra</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

how can I get the label side by side the select?
I have tried with the `form-horizontal` but doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use `form-inline` instead of `form-horizontal` and you can also use this link for your references http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Answer (score 1):

Add `form-inline` class to your `<form>` tag
Like so:

```
<form class="form-inline">
```

Comment: Try removing  <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-2"> from inside the form and let form-inline and <div class="form-group"> do their magic. Take a good look at the documentation and you'll figure it out.